# Regex, how to see if a a string contains 3 possible patterns atleast twice

Tags: regex

I haven't used regex much and I'm trying to learn a bit of it now.

I want to look for three possible patterns in a string at least two times. the patterns I'm looking for are at the start of a string, it can be `2;` , somewhere in the middle of a string, it can be `;2;` and at the end of a string, it can be `;2`

The what I'm doing now is `(^2;.*|.*;2;.*|.*;2$){2}`.

This seems to work for the most part, but I cant figure out why `a2;2;2` isn't matching. the `;2;`, and `;2` should match I believe.

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: The reason it's not matching is because the matches overlap, and `{2}` won't find overlapping matches. You should use lookarounds so that the `;` aren't part of the match.

Comment: Are you sure you want to include the delimiters in your matches? I have a feeling you're just looking for instances of `2` that appear in proper places within the string. Maybe try something like `(?<=^|;)2(?=$|;)` https://regex101.com/r/0PoJZz/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantifiers won't count overlapping occurrences of the pattern. Since the `;` characters are included in the match, you won't find matches where the ending `;` of one match is the starting `;` of the other.

You can solve this by using lookarounds to take the `;` out of the match.

```
(?<=^|;)2(?=;).*(?<=;)2(?=;|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uVEwcG/1)

Answer (score 2):

You could try (with look-arounds around the `2`):

```
(?:^2(?=;)|(?<=;)2(?=;)).*(?<=;)2(?=;|$)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/cnZnkk/1)